# Can't Decrypt Twilio recording using PHP

Tags: php, encryption, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I'm trying to decrypt encrypted Twilio recording using **PHP**

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/voice-recording-encryption#step-5

[image: Step 5: Decrypt using private key and encryption parameters]

This is my Encryption Details:
[image: Encryption Details]

I have successfully perform first step:

```
$privateKey = openssl_get_privatekey('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- *****');

    $result = openssl_private_decrypt(
        base64_decode('< encrypted_cek  from EncryptionDetails >'),
        $decryptedKeyData,
        $privateKey,
        OPENSSL_NO_PADDING
    );
```

Then I'm trying to decrypt recording using `openssl_decrypt` function:

```
$data = base64_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC***/Recordings/RE***'));

$tag = substr($data,-16);

$decrypt = openssl_decrypt(
    $data,
    'aes-256-gcm',
    $decryptedKeyData,
    0,
    '< IV  from EncryptionDetails >',
    $tag
);

$decrypt = openssl_decrypt(
    $data,
    'aes-256-gcm',
    $decryptedKeyData,
    0,
    '< IV  from EncryptionDetails >',
);
```

Have tried many different variants, with and without `$tag` but the result is always `false`.

Where can I get the error?

Comment: @philnash Hey Phil. I know you're an expert in Twilio. Maybe you can give me any advice?

Comment: Hi @AlekseyBoyko, I know lots about Twilio, but not a lot about decryption in PHP and that seems to be where the issue lies. I don't think I can help here. Hopefully someone else with better PHP knowledge than me can help out!

Comment: Oh, actually, there is an example that might help you. Check out [this pull request](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/encrypted-media-recordings/pull/75/files) which is an example of decrypting in PHP.

Comment: Awesome! I hope to see that PR merged soon too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I am not a PHP developer, so don't know how to direct you regarding decryption in PHP. But, you can check out [this pull request](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/encrypted-media-recordings/pull/75/files) which is an example of decrypting Twilio media in PHP and may help you figure it out.

Comment: I didn't find a solution for PHP, so I made my own :)